# Initialize std::array with implied length

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdarray

In C you can do `int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}`, but C++11 `std::array<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5}` will give a "too few template parameters" compile error. Any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can have is a `make_array`, something like:

```
template<typename T, typename...Ts>
constexpr std::array<T, 1 + sizeof...(Ts)> make_array(T&& head, Ts&&...tail)
{
     return {{ std::forward<T>(head), std::forward<Ts>(tail)... }};
}
```

Comment: Why is it `1 + sizeof...(Ts)`? What is the extra space for?

Comment: @0x499602D2: `1` is for the first parameter `T head` (we deduce the type from the `head`).

Answer (score -3):

Implementation of std::array:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array {
    T array_impl[N];
};
```

So this Should work:

```
std::array<std::int, 5> a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};
```

which is essentially just like (as the compiler agreed to drop off the inner curly brackets.

```
std::array<std::int, 5> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

See

Comment: So how can you do that without saying that the length of the array is 5?

Comment: you do specify the array Rikayan, look at the second template parameter that's passed to the template..

Comment: @DoryZidon This doesn't answer what he is asking.